# asp.net error creating control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just opened my asp.net solution and am getting this message on every control on my application!

here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="EnterData.DataEntry.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />


        <br /><table>
                <tr>  
                <td>
                lom_number:
                </td>
               <td><asp:TextBox ID="lom_numberTextBox" runat="server"
                    Text=''/></td>

                <td>occurrence_date:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="occurrence_dateTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("occurrence_date") %>' />

                    <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1"
    TargetControlID="occurrence_dateTextBox" 
    Mask="99/99/9999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" 
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    MaskType="Date" 
    InputDirection="RightToLeft" 
    AcceptNegative="Left" 
    DisplayMoney="Left"
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" runat="server"/></td>
                <td>report_date:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="report_dateTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("report_date") %>' /></td>
                    <td>spec_id:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="spec_idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("spec_id") %>' /></td>             
                    </tr>
                <tr>


                <td>batch_id:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="batch_idTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("batch_id") %>' /></td>
                <td>report_by:</td>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="report_byTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("report_by") %>' /></td>

                <td>identified_by:</td> 


                <td><asp:TextBox ID="identified_byTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("identified_by") %>' /></td>
                <td>problem:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="problemTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("problem") %>' /></td>
                <td></td>
               </tr></table>
               <table><tr><td>section_c_issue_error_identified_by:</td>
               <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox"  width="500" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("section_c_issue_error_identified_by") %>' />
                    </td></tr>
                <tr><td>section_c_comments:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="section_c_commentsTextBox" Width="500" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("section_c_comments") %>' /></td></tr>
               <tr><td>section_d_investigation:</td><td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="section_d_investigationTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("section_d_investigation") %>' /></td></tr>
               <tr><td>section_e_corrective_action:</td>  <td><asp:TextBox ID="section_e_corrective_actionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("section_e_corrective_action") %>' /></td></tr>
               <tr><td>section_f_comments:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="section_f_commentsTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("section_f_comments") %>' /></td></tr>


                </table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="SubmitData" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: In Design Mode, what does the ToolTip say within the errors?

Comment: @shredder there is no tooltip for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just happened to me. It happened when I renamed page and moved aspx file within project folders, but code inside left unrenamed.

Change code inside from:

```
public partial class foldername_unrenamedname : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

to current

```
public partial class newfoldername_renamedname : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

And also edit Inherits property in Page tag to:

```
Inherits="Newfoldername_renamedname"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this error by following the below steps , the root cause of this error is the incorrect mapping between web application project and the virtual directory in your IIS.

To Resolve this error , follow the following steps:

1-Right click - you web application project and select Properties -> Web

2- in the server section choose Use IIS Web Server -> then click Create Virtual.

3- Clean your project and compile again.

done :)

This info is on following site.

http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/archive/2007/09/15/resolving-error-creating-control-xxx-in-web-application-project.aspx

Here is another article which proposed different solution and cause there is that object is not initialized before use.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/06/another-error-creating-control-in-the-design-view-with-object-reference-not-set-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Closed the aspx designer, cleaned the project and rebuild it, everything started working perfectly. (using Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with all my pages. I changed the version of .NETFramework and it worked.
The version of .NETFramework at the time when components were added was different from the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried all of the above but none of them worked for me.

What did work was the following:
Go to Project->Properties click on Web and then change the Server (mine was defined as Local IIS) to External IIS and Save.

I didn't even have to restart VS and the controls re-appeared correctly.

Once you get your controls to appear properly, you can change your Web->Server settings back to what they were before.